# Replacing NULL value in a column by a value from previous column Snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have some sample data in table `temp` as follows;

| name | week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bamboo | 56 | null | null | null |
| Pearl | 42 | null | 43 | 12 |
| ZZplant | 42 | null | null | 13 |
| Pothos | 12 | 10 | null | 0 |

Here we need to replace null values in a column by non null values in previous column. Hence we she have the output as;

**Expected output**

| name | week1 | week2 | week3 | week4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Bamboo | 56 | 56 | 56 | 56 |
| Pearl | 42 | 42 | 43 | 12 |
| ZZplant | 42 | 42 | 42 | 13 |
| Pothos | 12 | 10 | 10 | 0 |

Here is my attempt,

```
with week2 as(
select name,
       week1,
       coalesce(week2,week1) as week2,
       week3,
       week4

from temp),

 week3 as(
select name,
       week1,
       week2,
       coalesce(week3, week2) as week3,
       week4

from week2)

select name,
       week1,
       week2,
       week3,
       coalesce(week4, week3) as week4

from week3;
```

As seen, I am coalescing one column at a time. This seems to be working but is not scalable. Is it possible To get some advice/help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    week1,
    COALESCE(week2, week1) AS week2,
    COALESCE(week3, week2, week1) AS week3,
    COALESCE(week4, week3, week2, week1) AS week4
    -- each column has expression containing all prev columns
FROM temp1;
```

Alternatively using the fact we could refer to column expression at the same level:

```
SELECT 
    t.name,
    t.week1 AS week1_,
    COALESCE(t.week2, week1_) AS week2_,
    COALESCE(t.week3, week2_) AS week3_,
    COALESCE(t.week4, week3_) AS week4_
    -- each column refers only to previous alias
FROM temp1 AS t;
```

---

For sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE temp1(name TEXT, week1 INT, week2 INT, week3 INT, week4 INT)
AS    SELECT 'Bamboo',  56  ,null   ,null   ,null
UNION SELECT 'Pearl',   42  ,null   ,43     ,12
UNION SELECT 'ZZplant', 42  ,null   ,null   ,13
UNION SELECT 'Pothos',  12  ,10     ,null   ,0;
```

Output:

```
NAME    WEEK1_  WEEK2_  WEEK3_  WEEK4_
Bamboo  56  56  56  56
Pearl   42  42  43  12
Pothos  12  10  10  0
ZZplant 42  42  42  13
```